# Looker Data Studio Sum KPIs by period

Tags: case, looker-studio, sumifs, multiple-conditions

I have data set where in Column C I have periods "Jan 2023", "Feb 2023" etc. In Column D-L I have some KPIs and I need to create new KPI which is Sum of KPI in Column D.
But if I choose for Example Jan 2023 in Date Range control this field should sum data from Column D 11 months Back.
so for Example: If period = Jan 2023 then Sum Column D where period= (Dec 2022 -Feb 2022)
Is it possible to create field like this?

Thank you

I tried to create some if function but it did not work

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.